# MySQL from two tables with one left join

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables with almost the same columns - a list of videos and a list of galleries. I want to then left join this to the members table so I can get the members name from the member ID. What I end up with is a list of videos and galleries ordered by the date column. I know how to do it separately but can't get it to work combined. Here are the separate queries:

```
//Video Query
SELECT videos.vid, videos.mid, videos.source, videos.category, videos.title, videos.description, videos.date_added, videos.status, members.name FROM videos LEFT JOIN members ON videos.mid=members.mid WHERE videos.status = 'published' ORDER BY date_added

//Gallery Query    
SELECT galleries.vid, galleries.mid, galleries.directory, galleries.category, galleries.title, galleries.description, galleries.date_added, galleries.status, members.name FROM videos LEFT JOIN members ON videos.mid=members.mid WHERE galleries.status = 'published' ORDER BY date_added
```

But I can't get it to work with the left join with two tables. Both tables use the same column for left joining and same column for sorting. Can I do it one query or do I have to query both and do some kind of merge?

The end result would be something like:

```
- Video A by John
- Gallery A by John
- Video B by John
- Video C by Mary
```

Etc

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both the query and write something like

```
SELECT 
  videos.vid,
  videos.mid,
  videos.source,
  videos.category,
  videos.title,
  videos.description,
  videos.date_added,
  videos.status,
  galleries.vid,
  galleries.mid,
  galleries.directory,
  galleries.category,
  galleries.title,
  galleries.description,
  galleries.date_added,
  galleries.status,
  members.name 
FROM
  videos 
  LEFT JOIN members 
    ON videos.mid = members.mid members.name 
FROM
  videos 
  LEFT JOIN members 
    ON videos.mid = members.mid 
    AND videos.status = 'published' 
  LEFT JOIN galleries 
    ON galleries.mid = members.mid 
AND galleries.status = 'published' 
ORDER BY galleries.date_added,videos.date_added
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry that didnt work. First it returned an error so removed that first from block but then it returned the gallery rows merged to video rows which isnt what I wanted.